# How to accept space in react-select?

Tags: reactjs

The following component is responsible for searching for data that has already been obtained from the database:

The problem is that it doesn't let me use spaces, for example I want to search for "Silobolsa Pepe" and it would only let me search like this "SilobolsaPepe"

But I wanted to know if you, who have more experience, have any other ideas.

```
const DropdownIndicator = () => {
  return <></>;
};

const Control = ({ children, ...props }: any) => (
  <components.Control {...props} className="cursor-text ellipsis">
    {children}
  </components.Control>
);

  const SeachInput = (
    <Form>
      <div className="navBarInputSize">
        <Form.Group controlId="form-sil" className="input-search">
          <InputGroup hasValidation className="no-wrap">
            <Select
              className={"search-input-navbar"}
              placeholder="Search Silobag.."
              components={{ DropdownIndicator, Control }}
              options={
                siloBagData.silobagList && siloBagData.silobagList.length > 0
                  ? siloBagData.silobagList
                      .filter((value: any) =>
                        searchValue === ""
                          ? false
                          : value.name.toUpperCase().indexOf(searchValue) > -1
                      )
                      .map((value: any) => ({
                        value,
                        label: value.name,
                      }))
                  : []
              }
              onInputChange={(e: any) => setSearchValue(e.toUpperCase())}
              onChange={(e: any) =>
                navigate(Paths.VIEW_SILO, {
                  state: {
                    from: path,
                    record: e.value,
                  },
                })
              }
            />
            <InputGroup.Text
              id="inputGroupPrepend"
              className={"navBarInputSearch"}
            >
              <Image style={{ height: "12.28", width: 13 }} src={SearchIcon} />
            </InputGroup.Text>
          </InputGroup>
        </Form.Group>
      </div>
    </Form>
  );
```

The Select belongs to the react-select library, this is the configuration it has:

```
declare type StateManagedSelect = <Option = unknown, IsMulti extends boolean = false, Group extends GroupBase<Option> = GroupBase<Option>>(props: StateManagerProps<Option, IsMulti, Group> & RefAttributes<Select<Option, IsMulti, Group>>) => ReactElement;
declare const StateManagedSelect: StateManagedSelect;
export default StateManagedSelect;
```

From what I searched for, most likely it was along this line: `onInputChange={(e: any) => setSearchValue(e.toUpperCase())}` which basically makes everything you write is sent in uppercase , and so the "space" is not being recognized.